# How to list all functions in a script which are only defined in that file?

Tags: python

I have used the below code to extract functions in a file:

```
from requests.utils import quote

def create_methods_dict( module, methods_dict ):
   for name, obj in inspect.getmembers( module ):
      method_list = []
      if inspect.isclass( obj ):
         for attribute in dir( obj ):
            attribute_value = getattr( obj, attribute )
            if callable( attribute_value ):
               if attribute.startswith( '__' ) == False:
                  method_list.append( attribute )
         methods_dict[name] = method_list
```

The `methods_dict` container contains all the functions but also includes functions which are part of the imported module. I want to avoid functions which are part of imported modules. How can I achieve that?
(I see the functions of the above two imported modules as part of the dict.)

(The above code is part of some other code. I have not included all the required modules for this code to work.)

Comment: How could a script contain any functions **not** defined within it?

Comment: The same concern I have. I thought I would have written something wrong in the function. If not then is there a way to  know if the function is defined in the same file?

Comment: Know if the function is defined in the same file as *what*?

Comment: Actually I want to store all the names of functions which are defined in that file. As with the above code even the functions(name) which are part of an imported module gets included ( in my storage which is a dictionary ), I am not able to use it for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem you claim you had in a comment where your code was putting functions and methods imported from other other modules into the `method_list`. Below is an example code demonstrating thiat does happen.:

```
import inspect

def create_methods_dict(module, methods_dict):
   for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
      method_list = []
      if inspect.isclass(obj):
         for attribute in dir(obj):
            attribute_value = getattr(obj, attribute)
            if callable(attribute_value):
               if attribute.startswith('__') == False:
                  method_list.append(attribute)
         methods_dict[name] = method_list


def Function1(): pass


class Class1:
    def method1(self): pass
    def method2(self): pass

class Class2:
    def method1(self): pass
    def method2(self): pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import __main__
    import random
    import time

    methods_dict = {}
    create_methods_dict(__main__, methods_dict)
    print(methods_dict)  # -> {'Class1': ['method1', 'method2'], 
                               'Class2': ['method1', 'method2']}
```

Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71630029/edit) your question and add a runnable [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).